# dígitos repetidos: suma, porcentaje, cantidad de repeticiones

Tags: python, diccionarios, caracteres, contenedores

Tengo este ejercicio por realizar y la verdad es que no se me ocurre que hacer.

Escribir un programa que solicite el ingreso de números enteros hasta leer uno que no tenga dígitos repetidos.
Se pide informar:

- Para cada número, la suma de los dígitos que se repiten en ese
  número.
- Para cada número, la cantidad de dígitos que se repiten en ese
  número.
- Al finalizar, el porcentaje de números procesados mayores que 478.
- Al finalizar, el promedio de los números procesados

Hasta el momento solo tengo esto (informa cuantos dígitos se repiten):

```py
ingr = int(input("ingrese un numero: "))
diccio = dict()
contador = 0
for i in str(ingr):
    if i in diccio:
        if diccio[i] == 1:
            contador += 1
        diccio[i] += 1
    else:
        diccio[i] = 1
    print (contador)
```

gracias!!

Comment: Te recomiendo hacer cada inciso por códigos separado, para que tengas más claro conceptos y no mezcles. En lo posible también que las preguntas sean puntuales e individualizadas, evitar poner el enunciado de tareas tal cual.

Comment: El `int()` con el `str()` se anulan mutuamente. Puedes eliminar esas llamadas para simplificar el código.

Answer (score 0):

**Para la primera parte del ejercicio:**

Te pide ingresar números, pero casi todas las operaciones las puedes hacer con el string del input.

Como en python no existe `Do ... While` lo puedes emular con

```
while True:
    num = input('dame un número')
    if len(num) == len(set(num)): break
```

Así puedes comparar una cadena con esa cadena sin repetidos.
Para completar un poco el código puedes confirmar que realmente esten introduciendo un número y que no sea una cadena vacía

```
while True:
    num = input('dame un número')
    if num == '': continue
    if not num.isdecimal() or len(num) == len(set(num)): break
```

para guardar los digitos que se repiten creas una lista con los dígitos que se repiten. Aquí si te puede interesar pasarlo a decimal `int(x)`

```
    repes = []
    for x in set(num):
        if num.count(x) > 1:
            repes.append(int(x))
```

que con *comprension de listas* queda así:

```
    repes = [int(x) for x in set(num) if num.count(x) > 1]
```

El código para la primera pregunta completo:

```
msg = 'dígitos que se repiten en ese número es'
while True:
    num = input('dame un número')
    if num == '': continue
    if not num.isdecimal() or len(num) == len(set(num)): break
    
    repes = [int(x) for x in set(num) if num.count(x) > 1]

    print(f'La suma de los {msg} {sum(repes )}')
    print(f'La cantidad de {msg} {len(repes)}')
```